# How to bypass SpriteBatch sorting? C# XNA

Tags: c#-4.0, xna

I am working on a "falling sand" game in XNA. Of course, that means lots and lots of pixels must be drawn! It started fine, using a transparent blue color per pixel purely for testing algorithms. I was able to draw about 100,000 pixels to the screen before losing any frame rate (a steady 60 FPS), which was more than I needed! However, when I finally added a different color pixel (blue and red) and no other changes, my FPS dropped exponentially, only allowing for about 10,000 pixels to be drawn to the screen before FPS dropped to about 10. After experimenting some, I concluded that the sprite batch was most likely at fault, although I could be completely wrong and please let me know if you think of something different, because the sprite batch automatically sorts and blends the pixels together. I assume the act of blending the two colors together is where I am losing speed. So, how could I get around the sprite batch's methods? Or am I completely off base?

I've tried messing with SpriteSortMode and BlendMode, and even only drawing like colored pixels per sprite batch call, but no luck so far.

Also, the pixels I am drawing to the screen never have the same coordinates to begin with, so blending and the like is not needed.

```
    //Game Draw Method
    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {                      
        stopWatch.Start();          

        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.Black);

        spriteBatch.Begin();

        //backgroundSprite.Draw(spriteBatch);

        terrainSprite.Draw(spriteBatch);

        resourceMap.Draw(spriteBatch, spriteFont);            

        frameCounter++;

        string fps = string.Format("fps: {0}", frameRate);

        int totalint = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < resourceMap.activeCoordinates.Count; i++)
        {
            totalint += resourceMap.activeCoordinates[i].Count;
        }

        string total = string.Format("resource count: {0}", totalint);

        spriteBatch.DrawString(spriteFont, fps, new Vector2(33, 33), Color.White);
        spriteBatch.DrawString(spriteFont, total, new Vector2(33, 45), Color.White);
        spriteBatch.DrawString(spriteFont, totalTime, new Vector2(33, 17),    Color.White);            
        spriteBatch.DrawString(spriteFont, totalTime, new Vector2(33, 17),  Color.White); 


        spriteBatch.End();
        stopWatch.Stop();
        totalTime = "Draw Time:     " + stopWatch.Elapsed;
        stopWatch = new Stopwatch();


        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }

    //resourceMap.Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch, SpriteFont font) from Game Draw
    public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch, SpriteFont font)
    {
        //spriteBatch.End();
        //this was originally one for loop to draw all pixels, but was separated to draw each different color pixel after discovering performance issue
        for (int c = 0; c < activeCoordinates.Count(); c++)
        {
            //spriteBatch.Begin();
            for (int i = 0; i < activeCoordinates[c].Count; i++)
            {
                mapArray[(int)activeCoordinates[c][i].X][(int)activeCoordinates[c][i].Y].Draw(spriteBatch);
            }
            //spriteBatch.End();
        }
        //spriteBatch.Begin();
        spriteBatch.DrawString(font, timeInMilli, new Vector2(33, 0), Color.White);
    }
```

Again, the only change made to the code was adding different colors to the list of pixels to be drawn, so the code here was working great (100,000 pixels drawn at around 60fps) until I added an extra color.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: The code is as simple as a for loop with a draw method. It shouldn't help as much as the explanation, but there you go ^^.

Comment: Can you add code for whatever `mapArray[][].Draw` is? Although it's worth pointing out that drawing each pixel as its own individual sprite is very likely the wrong solution to this anyway.

Comment: I think you may solve your problem by drawing tinted white pixels, which is one texture for all sand particles, but with different coloring. It might raise the framerate, though the problem may be in something else you haven't posted. But yes, drawing a one pixel texture for each sand particle is a terribly slow approach. Try googling *powder* game and how they did it.

Comment: As a guess here, I cannot see from your code, if you are drawing all the blue then all the red, or if your drawing them as a mix. I would look at drawing 1 color then the other color if you can. this may not be possible depending on logic, but if you can minimize the amount of times the Spritebatch grabs a texture that may help.

Comment: @Jastill I think if you set SpriteSortMode to Texture, sprite batch will do it for you, but it may be not cool if some textures overlap, as their order may become undesirable

Comment: @Andrew Russell The mapArray[c][i].Draw is drawing the pixels (Yes, one at a time) where 'c' stands for the color index and 'i' is the pixel location. Presorting the colors like this did help the frame rate, although not as much as I would have liked.

Comment: @Andrew Russell Also, I attempted setting all the pixels to a Texture2D as each pixel updated, but this meant setting the color data of the result texture at the end of each update call (so 800*480 changes per update) which proved to be to slow to be useful. I would appreciate your ideas on the matter.

Comment: @user1306322 Powder game (atleast the one that I found, by Dan-Ball) only allows for about a fifth of the pixels I have used and the frame rate was actually worse in that game than what I've managed. So I guesss that one was a bad example... I'll look for others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I'm going to give the best answer I can, but I'm limited by the amount of code you've posted. First of all, I'd direct you to [this answer](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/37794/288) for an overview of the various factors that affect performance.

The problem you are likely to be experiencing with `SpriteBatch` is that you're forcing it to start too many batches. It must start a batch every time you change texture - and it sounds like you're using a different textures for different pixels, and then drawing them in random order.

Sorting by texture within `SpriteBatch` (with `SpriteSortMode.Texture`) can itself be an expensive operation. Your own code for grouping like-textured sprites might be slow or incorrect - but I can't tell with the code you've given.

A better case, rather than using many textures, would be to use a single, white texture, and then use the tint parameter to dynamically tint each sprite to the desired colour. Then every sprite can be sent in a single batch.

**BUT**, as well as a lot of processing to set up the vertices for so many sprites, we should consider how much data is actually being sent to the GPU. Each sprite has 4 vertices, each with a position, a colour, and a texture coordinate. That's a whopping **96 bytes** per pixel. And that all has to be sent to the GPU each frame!

A texture, on the other hand, is only **4 bytes** per pixel. So it stands to reason that it *should* be faster.

There are two things that could be slowing it down:

First of all, if you are calling `Texture2D.SetData` more than you have to. Each call to `SetData` requires a fairly substantial amount of overhead. If you call it once per pixel it is going to be extremely slow. Call it once for the entire image instead. That *should* make it fast enough to be usable - although I haven't tested this myself extensively.

The other possibility is that your GPU has a deep pipeline (hardware dependent) and is still using your texture to render frame N, while you are trying to update it for frame N+1. This forces the GPU to finish rendering frame N before it can accept the new changes. Although this seems unlikely to be a problem unless you are doing other very GPU-intensive things, or your graphics driver is doing something silly.

Comment: All of those were a problem that I had already fixed unfortunately, but the final fix I needed was setting the texture data ONE pixel at a time, instead of resetting the whole texture. After some research about setting one pixel at a time, all I found was posts saying it was impossible so I gave up on that. Then I finally figured out how to do it! Problem solved, but you covered a lot of important information so you mostly had the right answers.